# vb.Net console application running async after session

Tags: php, vb.net

I am trying to create a program that sets up a telnet connection to send data to a server that i host. trough command line with arguments. this application will be started trough PHP, but PHP will hold the page loading until the procces is done. which can take a while. so i am looking how to do the procces after the console application closed. to not make PHP wait until the task is fully done.
im trying to make the application a 'programmable' telnet connector for cmd
this is my current code:

```
Dim output As String = ""
    Dim telnet As TcpClient
    Dim Send As String
    Sub Main()
        Dim args As New List(Of String)
        Dim script As String = ""
        For Each arg As String In Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
            If (arg.Equals(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)) Then
                Continue For
            Else
                args.Add(arg)
            End If
        Next
        script = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(args(0))
        script = script.Replace("\;", "#comm_sla#")
        Dim script_in_part As List(Of String) = script.Split(";").ToList()
        Write("Found " + script_in_part.Count.ToString() + " lines")
        For Each scriptpart As String In script_in_part
            scriptpart = scriptpart.Replace("#comm_sla#", ";")
            scriptpart = scriptpart.Replace(";", "")
            scriptpart = scriptpart.Replace(vbNewLine, "")
            Write("Executing: " + scriptpart)
            Dim scr() As String = scriptpart.Split(" ")
            If scr(0).Equals("connect") Then
                Try
                    telnet = New TcpClient(scr(1), Integer.Parse(scr(2)))
                    Write("Connected")
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Write("Error=Cant connect, host or port meight be invalid")
                End Try
            End If
            If scr(0).Equals("disconnect") Then
                telnet.Client.Disconnect(False)
            End If
            If scr(0).Equals("start") Then
                If scr(1).Equals("session") Then
                    Write("Async session started")
                    Dim trh As Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf start_session)
                    trh.Start()
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Console.WriteLine(output)
    End Sub
    Private Sub start_session(state As Object)
        While True

connection meganism will come here

        MsgBox("test")
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End While
End Sub
Private Sub Write(ByVal str As String)
    output = output + str + ";"
End Sub
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you improve your description? I have a hard time understanding what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: its already solved by starting the program with START command trough cmd